# How can I make Ubuntu UI uniformly use bash keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

On my default 10.04 Ubuntu install I am consistently tripped up by the fact that some UI text areas/input boxes treat <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> as "select all" vs. "move my cursor to the beginning of the line." Is there some sort of global conf file that exists for these sorts of things?

I would really like to unify all text input areas to use bash conventions.

Comment: Might get more answers at http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are Emacs keybindings, and you can [enable them for Gtk applications](http://johan.kiviniemi.name/blag/emacs-key-bindings-in-gtk-apps/).

```
echo 'gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"' >>~/.gtkrc-2.0
gconftool -t string --set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme Emacs
```

Comment: Good answer.  But, for a number of reasons, you should include enough information from a link to keep your answer useful in the future if the link breaks.  I've updated this answer for you, but please keep this in mind in the future.